# Glassfish 2.0 Poodle vulnerability - How to disable SSL and allow TLS only

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, glassfish-2.x

Is there any JVM option or Grizzly framework config file to prevent SSLv3 connections ?
Somehow to disable SSLv3 and allow TLS cipher only.
Any other idea is welcome.

Comment: Have you considered to run GlassFish behind a reverse proxy (Apache HTTP) server? One could fix the Poodle vulnerability with just one line in the configuration file.

Comment: Maybe you can share this apache config. Even though this interface is internal on the oam interface and I have no means to put a proxy infront.

Comment: `SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3` (see also: https://bettercrypto.org/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have a web admin console in GlassFish 2? 
In GlassFish 3, the admin can disable SSLv3 under Network Config / Network Listeners / http-listener-n / SSL tab

See screenshots at http://javadude.wordpress.com/2010/04/06/getting-started-with-glassfish-v3-and-ssl/

Comment: that looks promising, I have the SSL tab. I have to test ... I will be back after some time